# How to wait for multiple network request to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I need to wait for two api calls to complete before calling a function with the returned data.

```
url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=18&format=json&accept-language=si&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon;

url2 = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=15&format=json&accept-language=si&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon;
```

```
$.when($.getJSON(url), $.getJSON(url2)).done(function (data1, data2) {
```

Here I need to add settimeout or interval with 2000 milliseconds between two getjson. 
After that can get response from one and second json response.
if is not transferred second json, not possible get response from first json

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your last statement is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to wait for more than one asyncronous function to finish is with `Promise.all` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Here's an example of a more contemporary way to write network calls using fetch:

```js
async function fetchMap([lat, lon]) {
  const request = await fetch(
    `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?zoom=18&format=json&accept-language=si&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`
  );
  return await request.json();
}

async function getMapData(coordinates1, coordinates2, callback) {
  const request1 = fetchMap(coordinates1)
  const request2 = fetchMap(coordinates2)

  const resolvedResponses = await Promise.all([request1, request2]);
  callback(...resolvedResponses);
}

// This will get data for Tokyo and New York,
// and wait to call the passed-in function until both sets of JSON data are return.

getMapData([35.6850, 139.7514], [40.6943,-73.9249], console.log);

/* ^ instead of "console.log" put a reference to whichever function you want to call.
It could be an anonymous function such as the one shown in your question. */
```

Comment: hello again, i have checked this is ok. but how can i get data from two different link. if you can check i have sent two different link. in url we have zoom=15 and zoom=18

Comment: @progy85 You can copy the `fetchMap` function, rename it, and change the URL. (does that help?)